# opening multiple modals with one function

Tags: javascript, button, modal-dialog

I have pictures with "learn more" button underneath. I'm trying to figure out how to write the js with each button showing different modal content.

```
    var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("myModal");
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    };
```

html looks like:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <h3>Bobcats</h3>
<img/>
        <button id="myBtn">Learn More</button>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>
            </p>
        </div></div>
```

I have 5 sections that need to be shown. Each additional section looks like the one above. I know the buttons need a unique id and I think setting up the class is where I'm running into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't repeat ID's in a page ... they are unique by definition.

Use classes and loop over the class collection to deal with instances, something like:

```js
// collection of galleries
var galleries = document.getElementsByClassName('gallery');
// iterate galleries collection
for (var i = 0; i < galleries.length; i++) {
  let gal = galleries[i], // specific gallery instance
    modal = gal.querySelector('.modal'), // modal within this gallery instance
    learnBtn = gal.querySelector('.learn');//button within this gallery instance

  let toggleModal = function(){
   modal.classList.toggle('show');
  };
  
  learnBtn.onclick = modal.onclick = toggleModal;

  
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
}

.modal.show {
  display: block;
  background: #eaeaea;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0
}

.modal-content {
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  margin: 20%;
  padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <h3>Gallery 1</h3>

  <button class="learn">Learn More</button>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>Gallery 1 modal
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
  <h3>Gallery 2</h3>

  <button class="learn">Learn More</button>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p>Gallery 2 modal
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```